# How to skip specific data from nested json in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a nested json, and i used the following code to extract, and it lists all the data from it, however i want to skip a particular data

Say the list is this

```
$ip = Array ( [0] => 1.1.1.1 [1] => 1.1.1.2 [2] => 1.1.1.3 [3] => 1.1.1.4 [4] => 1.1.1.5 )
```

I want to list all the IPs in a line and i can achieve that with following code in php

```
foreach ($ip as $character) {
    $state .= "<div 'col-sm-7 text-left'>$character<br></div>";;
    }
```

However say i want to skip 1.1.1.3, how can i do that?

I want the output to be like

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($ip as $character) {
    if ('1.1.1.3' !== $character) {
        $state .= "<div 'col-sm-7 text-left'>$character<br></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I have 1 more query, can you help me with it?
This is a code i made of your suggestion - https://3v4l.org/Bh6JK

however i want to move the first line (extra ips) within the foreach function, but when i do it, it repeats everytime for each IP, anyway to prevent it?

Comment: That's why how `foreach` works - it __repeats__ action every time. What's the problem with setting this header outside `foreach`?

Comment: That's not php problem. that's markup bug - css + html. Open developers console and try to find out why this happens and what need to be fixed.